# Plain Old Data - Alignment requirements

Tags: c++, struct, language-lawyer

Suppose I have two POD structs `A` and `B` with the same initial sequence of members, but some differences later (I know, this could easily be solved with inheritance).

```
struct A {
    int x;
    uint64_t y;
    int z;
};
struct B {
    int x;
    uint64_t y;
    int8_t z;
};
```

A pointer to the struct needs to point to the intitial member (§9.2.20 [class.mem]).

Now two additional questions:

- Where in the standard to I find that members cannot be reordered. I am pretty sure that this is the case, because the structs need to be fully compatible with C, and for C is prescribed that memory addresses must be increasing in the order of declaration.
- Must the alignment of the common members in both structs be the same? I.e., is the following always true:

  ```
  A a;
  B b;
  assert(offsetof(A, y) == offsetof(B, y));
  ```

  If not: At least if I put the structs into a union, then this should hold, because the standard (§9.2.19 [class.mem]) says

  > If a standard-layout union contains two or more standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence, and if the standard-layout union object currently contains one of these standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them.

---

I add here an additional example.

```
struct A {
    int x;
    uint64_t y;
    int z;
};
struct B {
    int x;
    uint64_t y;
    int8_t z;
};
B convertToB(A& a);
void g() {
    A a;
    // at this point, I cannot rely on offset(A, y) == offset(B, y)
    B b = convertToB(a);
    // since I do the copy over the union, offset(A, y) == offset(B, y) holds
}
union U {
     A asA; 
     B asB;
};
B convertToB(A& a) {
    U u;
    // at this point, offset(A, y) == offset(B, y) holds
    u.asA = a;
    return u.asB;
}
```

Since I have no chance to know whether at some point, a copy over a union happens, and a struct must be the same everywhere, I claim, that `offset(A, y) == offset(B, y)` must hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find oredering requirements for object members here:

> **9.2/13:** Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class **with the same access control** are allocated so that later members have higher
>   addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static
>   data members with **different access control is unspecified**.
>   Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members
>   not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might
>   requirements for space for managing virtual functions and virtual base
>   classes.

In your `struct` all the members have the same access class, so you have here a guarantee about the order.

Note however the last sentence of the quote: it is not guaranteed that the space between two consecutive members would be the same (although not very probable). This is why I'd recommend to go for the `union` approach.  Not only would you benefit from the standard's guarantees, but in addition you would clearly communicate your intent in the source code.

---

**Edit**

There's another aspect that we can consider:  a POD type is a trivial type and has a standard layout.

> **9.2/16:** Two standard-layout struct types are layout-compatible if they have the same number of non-static data members and corresponding
>   non-static data members (in declaration order) have layout-compatible
>   types
>
> **3.9/11:** If two types T1 and T2 are the same type, then T1 and T2 are layout-compatible types.

Once again, you see that you have no guarantees, as soon as your struct diverge at some point.  However I understand that this gives you the guarantee that `u.asB` is layout compatible with the `B` object it returns.

Finally, I hoped to find a more tangible guarantee with trivially copiable objects:

> **3.9/2:** For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of trivially copyable type T, whether or not the object holds a valid
>   value of type T, the underlying bytes making up the object can be
>   copied into an array of char or unsigned char. If the content of the
>   array of char or unsigned char is copied back into the object, the
>   object shall subsequently hold its original value.

I think that one can deduce from this, that in your case, storing one value in the union but reading the other would work. However be aware that this is not a general truth according to this (non normative) note:

> **9.5/4:** [Note: In general, one must use explicit destructor calls and placement new operators to change the active member of a union.
>   —end note]

Comment: That's true, especially your advice. I added an additional example, why I claim that the padding should be the same.

Comment: It's the safe approach. Hypothetically, suppose the layout wouldn't be the same, in the union and the raw struct.  The compiler would organise a member by member copy when you return u.asB to a temporary B object.

Comment: So, `U.asA` and `U.asB` must have the same layout, while `U.asA` and `A` respectively `U.asB` and `B` do not need to?